# Method .save() is inserting instead of update my model in adonis/node.js

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

I create a method to make a update in my controller, following the adonis [documentation](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.0/lucid) that says:

> The save method persists the instance to the database. Also, it
>   smartly figures out whether to create a new row or update the existing
>   row.

So i try this way:

```
update ({ request, auth }){

    let user = new User()
    user.merge(request.all())
    const user = await user.save()
    return user 
}
```

So i make a put request in this route and i receive this error:

> message: "insert into "users" ... "id" - duplicate key value violates
>   unique constraint "users_pkey""

How i can update a model? In the request i'm passing the id that i need to update, but the Lucid thinks that is a insert...

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the `const user =` since you already defined user two lines above that. This could be causing the unwanted functionality.

Comment: same problem, i fixed using let user = await User.findOrFail(request.params.id)

Answer (score 2):

Fixed using:

```
async update ({ request, auth }){

    let user = await User.findOrFail(request.params.id)
    user.merge(request.all())
    await user.save()
    return user

}
```